# Canvas Radial Gradient animation

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I need some help with my script. I'm trying to make the "bright spot" move along with the mouse on my `canvas` but it looks like it's moving way faster than the coursor. Where is the problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
    position:absolute;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
      canvas{
    position: fixed;
    height:900px;
    Width:900px;
    }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    <script>
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      window.onmousemove=function(){
      context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      context.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      // create radial gradient
      var grd = context.createRadialGradient(event.clientX, event.clientY, 5, event.clientX+20, event.clientY+20, 100);
      // light blue
      grd.addColorStop(0, '#ffffff');
      // dark blue
      grd.addColorStop(0.5, '#000000');

      context.fillStyle = grd;
      context.fill();
      };

    window.onclick= function(){
        alert("X: " + event.clientX + " " +"Y: " + event.clientY)
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are resizing your canvas with CSS without setting its own width and height properties. The context is only aware of this properties' sizes, not of the displayed (CSS)ones. Also note that creating an gradient at every mouse move is generally a bad idea. Instead draw once your gradient on an offscreen canvas, and then draw this offscreen canvas at correct positions.

Comment: OK, now I get it. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the mouse events and rendering separate as mouse events are not synced to the display. Mouse events just record mouse state (up to and over 100+ samples a second.) Animation frames render only when able to display the canvas content 60fps.

Just create the gradient once and move it using the transformation functions in the 2D canvas API.

Also make sure that the canvas resolution (number pixels on the canvas) matches the number of CSS pixels the canvas occupies.

```js
// start the main loop when ready
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
// get the canvas context
const ctx = can.getContext("2d");
// set up mouse
document.addEventListener("mousemove", mEvent);
function mEvent(e) { mouse.x = e.pageX; mouse.y = e.pageY }
const mouse = { x: 0, y: 0 };
// create gardient
const grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100);
grad.addColorStop(0, "rgb(255,255,255)");
grad.addColorStop(1, "rgb(0,0,0)");
// requestAnimationFrame callback function
function mainLoop() {
  // resize canvas if needed
  if (can.width !== innerWidth || can.height !== innerHeight) {
    can.width = innerWidth; // resize canvas if 
    can.height = innerHeight; // window resized
  }
  // set canvas origin to the mouse coords (moves the gradient)
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, mouse.x, mouse.y);
  ctx.fillStyle = grad;
  // fill canvas with a rectangle
  ctx.fillRect(-mouse.x, -mouse.y, can.width, can.height);
  requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
```

```css
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="can"></canvas>
```